# guava - map backed guava function

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I want to create a read-only Map backed by a guava Function. I have a function which provides the value, given a key.

```
Function f = new Function() {
    public Object apply(final Object key) {
        return ...;
     }
};

Map m = mapBasedOnFunction(f); // is this possible with Guava?

m.get(some key); // the value is provided by the function
```

Is this possible with Guava?

I understand that iteration, size(), ... will not work, which is not required here. Actually, I only need the get() function to be functional.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not implement java.util.Map - the get implementation will call your function, although you'll have fun deciding what to do in size(), containsKey, and some others...

Comment: I prefer to use a Guava function, if it exists alteast, instead of creating my own implementations.

Comment: There's no such thing in Guava. Basically you want a `Map`-shaped wrapper for your `Function` instead of calling it directly, which I don't believe is a common or frequent use case. Why not call the `Function` directly? That's its definition.

Comment: This _was_ supported with `MapMaker`, but has been deprecated and pushed back on specifically because it's such a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `Maps.toMap` but you need to supply an `Iterable` of keys.

```
Function f = ...
Set keys = ...
Map map = Maps.toMap( keys, f );
```

Without the keys the map can't really handle `.size()` or `.entrySet()`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the inverse is possible. You use Functions.forMap() and give it a Map which this call turns into a Function that can work as a mapping table.

I'm not sure you can do that with Guava.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your are trying to accomplish here but - like George mentioned - something like this should work:

```
public class FunctionMap extends HashMap<Object, Object> {
    private Function<Object, Object> function;

    public FunctionMap(Function<Object, Object> function) { this.function = function; }

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) { return function.apply(key); }
}
```